# Cross-Database information_schema Joins in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-migration

I am attempting to provide a general solution for the migration of data from one schema version to another. A problem arises when the column data type from the source schema does not match that of the destination. I would like to create a query that will perform a preliminary compare on the columns data types to return which columns need to be fixed before migration is possible.

My current approach is to return the table and column names from `information_schema.columns` where `DATA_TYPE`'s between catalogs do not match. However, querying `information_schema` directly will only return results from the catalog of the connection.

Has anyone written a query like this?

Comment: Are the schemas identical other than datatype?

Answer (score 3):

I do this by querying the system tables directly. Look into the `syscolumns` and `sysobjects` tables.  You can also join across linked servers too

```
select t1.name as tname,c1.name as cname
from adventureworks.dbo.syscolumns c1
join adventureworks.dbo.sysobjects t1 on c1.id = t1.id 
where t1.type = 'U' 
order by t1.name,c1.colorder
```

Answer (score 2):

I have always been in the fortunate position to have Red Gate [Schema compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) which i think would do what you ask. Cheap at twice the price!

Comment: Red_gate makes good products that are resonably priced. Thier products are worth every penny,